# Finding operator norm of a functional.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

On $l^2$ define a functional $f$ by $f(x):=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{x_i}{i}, \forall x=(x_i)\in l^2.$ Is it bounded ? If so find $\|f\|.$

Ans: Note that $$|f(x)|=|\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{x
_i}{i}|\leq \|x\|_2 (\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i^2})^\frac{1}{2}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{6}} \|x\|_2, \forall x=(x_i)\in l^2. $$
This shows that $f$ is bounded and $\|f\|\leq \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{6}}.$
Please help me to get the norm of $\|f\|.$

Comment: What do you get when plugging in $x_i = 1/i$?

Comment: By considering $x=\frac{\sqrt6}{\pi} \{\frac{1}{i}\}\in l^2$ , I shall get the answer.. Thank you @JohnDoe